# Gotchas converting latin1_swedish_ci to utf8mb4_unicode_ci

Tags: mysql, character-set, utf-8

I have a MySQL 5.5.31 database which has approx 220 tables - of these 220 tables, around half of them are already using utf8mb4_unicode_ci but the "older" tables are still using latin1_swedish_ci. The fields in the tables are a mix of integer, varchar, longtext, date, datetime and decimal and there are no views or stored procedures.

I now have a requirement to support Russian text so I need to convert the remaining tables to UTF8. Based on my reading, I have opted for utf8mb4_unicode_ci as I believe it offers the broadest support including Chinese.

I have tested as much as I can with individual tables in a test environment without any issues and now need to bite the bullet and do this on my production database - I will, of course, take a full backup just before I make any changes.

I have read of some issues with converting TEXT and CHAR fields as well as some considerations on index sizes for VARCHAR fields but nothing else significant.

I know how to do this but I wanted a final sanity check to make sure there is nothing major I am missing before taking the plunge?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you will do this for each table?
`ALTER TABLE tbl CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;`

One potential issue involves the maximum of 767 bytes per column in an INDEX.  If you currently have a VARHAR(255) latin1 field in an index, you will need to rethink it.

- Decrease it to `VARCHAR(191)` if you are sure that 191 will suffice (into the future)
- Use a 'prefix' index:  `INDEX(foo(191))`.  This is often not worth doing.
- DROP the index.  (But not if you need the index; let's see the SELECT that needs it.)

**Edit**

For shrinking to `VARCHAR(191)`, you could write a Stored Procedure to look in `information_schema` to discover all the VARCHARs, and create and execute `SELECT MAX(CHAR_LENGTH(col)) ...` to see if any are over 191 (or even dangerously close to 191).  You might be surprised to find a few with max=255, implying that you may already have truncated some text.

The other two options won't damage data, but could have performance problems.

Comment: Yes that is the plan - my main concern is that I don't impact any existing data. I have millions of rows across 200 odd tables and I need to ensure the integrity of that data post changes. Like I said before, I have tried this in dev with no issues but now I have to bite the bullet I am nervous in case it impacts customer data

Comment: added an edit...

Comment: @RickJames I was reading https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/mysql-8-0-collations-migrating-from-older-collations/ and it also mentions the 767 limit, but it says 767 characters, not 767 bytes. Is one of these incorrect?

Comment: @jeremysawesome - I say 767 bytes:  https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits#767_limit_in_innodb_indexes  Note also that newer versions no longer need to watch out for 767.